# Multiple applications with single app.config

Tags: c#

I have 3 Console Applications projects using C#, say;

```
ConApp1.exe
ConApp2.exe
ConApp3.exe
```

Respectively their config files when compiled;

```
ConApp1.exe.config
ConApp2.exe.config
ConApp3.exe.config
```

All projects use identical configurations in config files but need separate application file each. I there a way, only single configuration file for all applications.

Comment: Name of config will be after name of exe. This won't be possible.

Comment: You have to create a batch or write code which will rename the config file according to the exe running.

Comment: cannot I do this with any separate config files in XML or JSON etc by pointing its locations

Comment: You also might like to see [Single config file for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495935/single-config-file-for-solution).